# Beginner Java Applet -- Cannot get swing timer to function

Tags: java, swing, timer, applet

I am working on a simple java applet that I want to keep adding up seconds infinitely (so there will be a g.drawString that adds 1 second non-stop. I have put in a swing timer into my applet, and I figure that the applet will repaint every 1 second (as I have set the timer to one second in my applet). I tried it out but the applet prints by thousands every second and not by ones.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class guitarGame extends Applet implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

Timer timer = new Timer (1000, this);
int amount;

public void init(){
    amount = 0;
    addKeyListener(this);
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ae){}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ae){

    repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ae){}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){}
public void paint (Graphics g)
{
    amount += 1;
    g.drawString(amount+"Seconds",400,400);
    repaint();
}
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Don't see the timer being started anywhere. Also why don't you use a Swing applet?

Comment: `amount` is counting the number of times `paint` has been invoked by the Swing framework, not seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`javax.swing.Timer` needs to be started in order to "click"

"Clicks" are triggered within the `actionPerformed` method within the assigned `ActionListener`

```
public class guitarGame extends Applet implements ActionListener, KeyListener {

    Timer timer = new Timer (1000, this);
    int amount;

    public void init(){
        amount = 0;
        //addKeyListener(this);
        timer.setRepeats(true);
        timer.starts();
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ae){}

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ae){

        repaint();
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent ae){}

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent ae){
        amount++;
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        // Do this or suffer increasingly bad paint artefacts
        super.paint(g);
        // This is the wrong place for this...
        //amount += 1;
        g.drawString(amount+"Seconds",400,400);
        // This is an incredibly bad idea
        //repaint();
    }
}
```